# Adding images to a UITextView

Tags: ios, image, cocoa-touch, uitextview

It appears that this has been asked and not answered before, but the question is ancient and there have been many Xcode / iOS updates since then, so I am going to give this a shot.

I have a simple view controller laid out. There is a single View that contains a read-only Text View with some instructions on how to use the app. I would like to intersperse some images in the scrolling text view to refer to the buttons and other elements that I am referring to in the instructions.

Here is the view:

[image]

So for instance, when the instructions refer to the green start button, I would like to insert an image of that button inline with the rest of the text.

I am using Xcode 5.1.1 and of course storyboards. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `NSAttributedString` with `NSTextAttachment` to attach an image to the text

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"press   to start"];
NSTextAttachment *imageAttachment = [NSTextAttachment new];
imageAttachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AnyImage.png"];
NSAttributedString *stringWithImage = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:imageAttachment];
[attributedString replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(5, 1) withAttributedString:stringWithImage];

self.textView.attributedText = attributedString;
```